# Sort sublists(Racket)

Tags: list, sorting, racket

Sort sublists

```
((b a c) (e d) (f h g) (d e) (k l i j) (n m) (o)) =>
((a b c) (d e) (f g h) (d e) (i j k l) (m n) (o))
```

in the language Racket. I've tried a lot of things, but it doesn't work. help solve the problem
I wrote this:

```
(define (order-by list order)
      (cond ((null? order) '())
        ((member (car order) list) (cons (car order) (order-by (removef (car order) list) order)))
        (#t (order-by list (cdr order)))))
       
  
(define (task list)
      (cond ((null? list) '())
            
                      (task (cdr list))))))
       
(print (task '((d a c) (q d) (f h g) (d e) (k l i j) (n m) (o))))
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Look up `map` and `sort`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(map (lambda (sublist) (sort sublist string<? #:key symbol->string)) 
     '((b a c) (e d) (f h g) (d e) (k l i j) (n m) (o)))
;;=> '((a b c) (d e) (f g h) (d e) (i j k l) (m n) (o))
```

In Common Lisp this is equal to:

```
(mapcar (lambda (sublist) (sort sublist #'string< :key #'string)) 
        '((b a c) (e d) (f h g) (d e) (k l i j) (n m) (o)))
;; => ((A B C) (D E) (F G H) (D E) (I J K L) (M N) (O))
```